# Redirecting a controller and action method to its URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project that I am working on that was done in `ASP.NET MVC 5`.

They used the default URL structure that comes standard with the framework. For example, the AGM page was constructed like this:

- Controller: Home
- Action method: AGM

Without any routing setup, to access this page, you would need to go to the following URL:

`www.example.com/Home/AGM`

This is the URL that they sent to the press. This URL looks horrible and I want to implement a cleaner URL structure which will look like this:

`www.example.com/agm`

I have set it up like this in the `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AGM",
    url: "agm",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AGM" }
);
```

What I want to achieve is if the user types in `www.example.com/Home/AGM` then it needs to display the URL like `www.example.com/agm`. Instead, it displays like `www.example.com/Home/AGM`.

I'm not sure how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure routing and define `action` in the `url`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AGM",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AGM" }
);
```

Then in the `AGM` method redirect to `www.example.com/agm`

```
if (Request.Path.ToLower() == "/home/agm")
{
    return Redirect("/agm");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but you just forgot the else part to `return View();`

Comment: Sure, I just wrote a part of code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `[Route("AGM")]` and `[Route("Home/AGM")]` top of your Action method:

```
[Route("AGM")]
[Route("Home/AGM")]
public IActionResult AGM()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when I type in `www.example.com/Home/AGM` then it goes to `www.example.com/Home/AGM` and not to `www.example.com/agm`.